# Is there a way to export .ai files as .psd files with warning dialog boxes turned off?

Tags: javascript, adobe-illustrator

My javascript function is supposed to export an .ai file as a psd file with no error dialog boxes, but the code isn't executing.

```
function exportFiletoPSD (dest) {
  if ( app.documents.length > 0 ) {
    var dest = Folder.selectDialog();
    var exportOptions = new ExportOptionsPhotoshop();
    var type = ExportType.PHOTOSHOP;
    var fileSpec = new File(dest);
    exportOptions.resolution = 300;
    exportOptions.warnings = false;
    app.activeDocument.exportFile( fileSpec, type, exportOptions );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what "isn't executing" means? It runs, but you get the dialog warnings? It runs but nothing happens? It errors out? It crashes your computer? (OK, that last one is unlikely, but you get the picture)

Comment: It seems as though the function isn't running, or it is but nothing happens in illustrator.  No folder select is brought up within illustrator, and no files are converted and exported. @cybernetic.nomad any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: How are you calling the function? Try changing the first line to `function exportFiletoPSD () {`

Answer (score 0):

For simple cases it works this way:

```
function exportFiletoPSD (dest) {
  if ( app.documents.length > 0 ) {
    // var dest = Folder.selectDialog(); // <-- it doesn't need if you provided 'dest' already
    var exportOptions = new ExportOptionsPhotoshop();
    var type = ExportType.PHOTOSHOP;
    var fileSpec = new File(dest);
    exportOptions.resolution = 300;
    exportOptions.warnings = false;
    app.activeDocument.exportFile( fileSpec, type, exportOptions );
  }
}

exportFiletoPSD('d:/temp/my_file.psd') // it saves current opened file in my_file.psd
```

There can be another features as well, it depends on your goals.